# How to convert String list to JSON Array Groovy

Tags: arrays, json, list, groovy

This is the problem that I'm trying to resolve. I have a list of map that I want to convert into JSON array in Groovy.

The list is:

```
List<Map<String, String>> studentList = [{id=1,name=John,email=john@google.com},{id=2,name=Peter,email=peter@google.com},{id=3,name=James,email=james@google.com}]
```

Desired JSON output is:

```
{
    students: [{
            "id" = "1",
            "name" = "John",
            "contact": {
                "email": "john@google.com"
            }
        }, {
            "id" = "2",
            "name" = "Peter",
            "contact": {
                "email": "peter@google.com"
            }
        }, {
            "id" = "3",
            "name" = "James",
            "contact": {
                "email": "james@google.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My code only generates 1 student. Can anyone help me please?

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
for (Map student: studentList) {
    builder.students {
        id student.id
        name student.name
        contact {
            email student.email
        }
    }
}
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

Appreciate your time and advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Pass a list to the builder

You don't need to iterate through the list, you can pass a list to the builder,
using JsonBuilder's implicit `call()` method.

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
  students builder( studentList )
}
```

#### public Object call( List list )

A list of elements as arguments to the JSON builder creates a root JSON array

See the [JsonBuilder Groovydoc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html#method_summary) page for details of the various `call()`
methods.

### Example code

In this example I've fixed up your map, and introduced a small Student class, to
simplify the code.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class Student { int id; String name; String email }

studentList = [
  new Student( id:1, name:'John',  email:'john@google.com'  ),
  new Student( id:2, name:'Peter', email:'peter@google.com' ),
  new Student( id:3, name:'James', email:'james@google.com' )
]

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
  students builder( studentList )
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

#### Resulting JSON

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "john@google.com",
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "peter@google.com",
      "name": "Peter"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "email": "james@google.com",
      "name": "James"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That almost solved my problem but as described, I have a slightly different target structure where the email is in a separate object.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with ff code.

```
def students = []

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
for (Map student: studentList) {
    builder {
        id student.id
        name student.name
        contact {
            email student.email
        }
    }
    students.add(builder.toString())
}
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def items = jsonSlurper.parseText(students.toString())

def json = new JsonBuilder()
json "students": items
println json.toPrettyString()
```